# Create function Error in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql

when I try to create a function to retrieve userName from user table using their email it gives me this useless error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DECLARE name VARCHAR; BEGIN select `userName` AS name from
>   `user` WHERE `ema' at line 2

, the same code with a different syntax works in mssql so I wonder what is the difference? in better words what am I doing wrong here?

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE FUNCTION getUserName(email varchar(50)) RETURNS VARCHAR
BEGIN
    DECLARE name VARCHAR;
    SELECT `userName` AS name FROM `user` WHERE `email` = email;
    RETURN name;
END ;;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all, varchar needs to have length, which you lack in two places. Also, you need to select into the variable and return the variable, because you cannot return resultset. Also you should escape name, and you do not need to alias your column because you are selecting into anyway. So, your code should be like this:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE FUNCTION getUserName(email VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN
    DECLARE NAME VARCHAR(50);
    SELECT `userName` FROM `user` WHERE `email` = email
    INTO `name`;
    RETURN `name`;
END ;;
```

Comment: it worked a treat thank you, and I like your comments now I know why it didn't work before